# Split header with tokenize by Spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel

It says  https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html#_using_tokenizer_from_spring_xml_extensions  that you can use the tokenizer expression in the Spring DSL to split bodies or **headers** using a token.

How can I split header with tokenize (for example I have in the header with name 'split' string "A@B@C" and I need split it by token "@")?

I thought I could do it as follows

```
<split>
      <header>split</header>
      <tokenize token="@"/>
      <to uri="mock:result"/> 
</split>
```

But when I save this code, I get an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: validation error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:
> Invalid content was found starting with element 'tokenize'. One of
> '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":aop,
> "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":aggregate,
> "http://camel.apache.org/schema

Camel version 2.25.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, the tokenize language has an option 'headerName' (Name of header to tokenize instead of using the message body) https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/tokenize-language.html.
This works

```
<split>
  <tokenize headerName="split" token="@"/>
  <to uri="mock:result"/>
</split>
```